# How to reach host behind site-to-site VPN connection through peering VPC connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-vpc, aws-vpc-peering, aws-site-to-site

I actually have following situation:
[image]

I successfully reach host C from Host A using VPN static routes. I need now to reach it from host B. I thought to create a route table from VPC B that forward request with ip/32 of host C through Peering connection... But it doesn't work.

There is a way to do that?

N.B. I cannot use Transit Gateway

Thanks!

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: I opted to use a Transit Gateway, thanks @Marcin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need now to reach it from host B.

You can't do this. VPC peering is [not transitive](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/invalid-peering-configurations.html#transitive-peering). You can setup VPC connection to VPC B as well instead.